# Unable to connect to the internet in 13.04 but fine in 12.04

Tags: internet

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04. Unfortunately, I can't access the internet. The same problem occurred with U 12.10. But with U 12.04 it's working perfectly well.

Comment: Wireless? Wired? More information. Show us `ifconfig -a` at the very least.

Comment: I am using a mobile broadband modem.First I am getting : "You are now registered on the home network". Few seconds later : "Disconnected. You are now offline".

Answer (score 0):

We need more information:

Open a terminal and show us the output of the following:

1. Show us the output of `ifconfig -a`
2. Can you ping your router `ping -C 10 192.168.0.1`
3. Show us the output of `dmesg`
4. Show us the output of `lspci`, `lsusb`

Is the connection WIRED? ie, plugged in.
Is the connection wireless? ie, no ethernet cable

Right now, all you've told us is that "it's not working".

Comment: I have the output but it's huge and (seems) impossible to display on AskUbuntu. Is it possible to send it to you by email?. Or, is there an alternative?

Comment: dmesg is usually quite big, you can start by showing us all the others.

Comment: eth0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:23:0c:34:bf  
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B Interrupt:17 
lo Link encap:Local Loopback  
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:5120 (5.1 KB)  TX bytes:5120 (5.1 KB)

Answer (score 0):

@ Brandon Bertelsen,

I'm having some of the same issues. The internet will run a little slower than in 12.10, but it still works, and then all of the sudden, no internet and I have to restart my computer. I have just installed 13.04 about a week ago or less and haven't been impressed with the internet speed and the internet kicking me off line......I did run that test that you posted for the above client, seems like everything is working properly, but it isn't. Any suggestions??

Comment: Hi all and especially B. Bertelsen,I just gave up trying!!! I am currently using a wireless router with my mobile modem. Everything is ok after installing the required firmware. Now, I can access the net from U 13.04. Thanks Brandon for trying to help.